# Named Type association with Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a type that associates names to types by mean of a Mapping Object Type `TMap`

it aims to feed a handler function with an association of one of the named types with a correspondent typed value

```
interface Thing<TMap extends { [k: string]: any }> {
  get<T extends keyof TMap>(handler: (v: TMap[T], t: T) => unknown): unknown
}
```

for example, say the Mapping Object type to be:

```
interface Types {
  num: number,
  dat: Date,
  str: string
}
```

and an instance of Things:

```
declare const thing: Thing<Types>
```

using the `get` method to get a couple of value, type works but loses type association when checking the type:

```
thing.get((v, t) => {
  // v: string | number | Date
  // t: "num" | "dat" | "str"
  if (t === 'num') {
    //  v: string | number | Date
    v
  } else if (t === 'dat') {
    //  v: string | number | Date
    v
  } else if (t === 'str') {
    //  v: string | number | Date
    v
  }
})
```

I managed a tricky workaround to fix that:

```
type Caster<TMap extends { [k: string]: any }> =
  <T extends keyof TMap>(
    v: TMap[keyof TMap],
    t: keyof TMap,
    isOfType: T
  ) => v is TMap[T]

declare const caster: Caster<Types>

thing.get((v, t) => {
  // v: string | number | Date
  // t: "num" | "dat" | "str"
  if (caster(v, t, 'num')) {
    //  v:  number 
    v
  } else if (caster(v, t, 'dat')) {
    //  v: Date
    v
  } else if (caster(v, t, 'str')) {
    //  v: string
    v
  }
})
```

How to properly declare `Thing` and `Thing.get` to keep type association avoiding tricky hacks?

[edit]
check it out on [TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Thing%3CTMap%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20get%3CT%20extends%20keyof%20TMap%3E(handler%3A%20(v%3A%20TMap%5BT%5D%2C%20t%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20unknown)%3A%20unknown%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20thing%3A%20Thing%3CTypes%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Types%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20num%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20dat%3A%20Date%2C%0D%0A%20%20str%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Athing.get((v%2C%20t)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(t%20%3D%3D%3D%20'num')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20v%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20Date%0D%0A%20%20%20%20v%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(t%20%3D%3D%3D%20'dat')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20v%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20Date%0D%0A%20%20%20%20v%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(t%20%3D%3D%3D%20'str')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20v%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20Date%0D%0A%20%20%20%20v%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Caster%3CTMap%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%3CT%20extends%20keyof%20TMap%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20v%3A%20TMap%5Bkeyof%20TMap%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20t%3A%20keyof%20TMap%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isOfType%3A%20T%0D%0A%20%20)%20%3D%3E%20v%20is%20TMap%5BT%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20caster%3A%20Caster%3CTypes%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Athing.get((v%2C%20t)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(caster(v%2C%20t%2C%20'num'))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20v%3A%20%20number%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20v%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(caster(v%2C%20t%2C%20'dat'))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20v%3A%20Date%0D%0A%20%20%20%20v%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(caster(v%2C%20t%2C%20'str'))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20v%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20v%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A)

Comment: Why not use `typeof v === 'number'` etc, that would work as a type guard directly on `v`. Otherwise are you willing to pass in a single object ? we could make that a discriminated union and narrow that

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir types of `v` could be anything - complex types too - depending on `Types` structure... It could clearly be done with custom type-guard-function for each type, but as it is guaranteed that for a certain typename `t` the `v` type will be exactly the associated one, I'd like to type-check only on typename `t` - (in fact `Caster<Types>` implementation would just check for equality of 2nd and 3rd argument ! ( `isOfType === t` )

Comment: Ok, so the simple guard version is out. The other point still stands. A check on one variable can't narrow the type of another variable. If both `t` and `v` were properties of the same object, we can check on `t` to narrow the whole object in effect narrowing `v`

Comment: I tested that too: handler function gets 1 single arg `(arg: { v: TMap[T], t: T })` and checking on `arg.t` .. no luck .. same issue .. :\

Comment: The type need to be a bit more creative .. I added an answer that would work with a single parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type guards don't support narrowing the type of a different value then the one checked.

What we can do is change the callback to take in an object that is a union where a member of a union has the form `{ type: P, value T[P] }` where `T` is the map type and `P` in turn every property of `T`

```
// Type that creates a union using the distributive property of union types.
type TypeUnion<T> = keyof T extends infer P ? // Introduce an extra type parameter P to distribute over
  P extends any ? { type: P, value: T[P] } :  // Take each P and create the union member
  never : never;

interface Thing<TMap extends { [k: string]: any }> {
  get(handler: (v: TypeUnion<TMap>) => unknown): unknown
}
declare const thing: Thing<Types>


interface Types {
  num: number,
  dat: Date,
  str: string
}

thing.get(o => { // o is  { type: "num"; value: number; } | { type: "dat"; value: Date; } | { type: "str"; value: string; }
  if (o.type === 'num') {
    o.value // number
  } else if (o.type === 'dat') {
    o.value // Date
  } else if (o.type === 'str') {
    o.value // string
  }
})
```

An alternative to conditional types for `TypeUnion` would be to use mapped type like this:

```
type TypeUnion<T> = {
  [P in keyof T] : { type: P, value: T[P]}
}[keyof T]
```

Comment: wow ! whats that `P extends any ? ` for ? why `P extends string ? ` won't work ?
Do you think there's no way to avoid packaging in one object ?
Any suggested good link ( other than typescriptlang.org ) to deepen distribution+infer topics ?

Comment: @aleclofabbro The `?` is just the start of a ternary that continues in the next line.

Comment: @IngoBürk yes i know about the conditional type.. but i don't understand that additional nested conditional..

Comment: @aleclofabbro the extra condition is just to introduce a new type parameter. Conditional types distribute over naked type parameters. To distribute over the union of keys we need to put them in a type parameter. The next `extends any` does the actual distribution, I don't actually care what `P` extends I just want to distribute over the union of keys that I now have in `P`

Comment: @aleclofabbro 99.99% sure there is no other way. Either a single object which we can narrow the type of, or a custom type guard as you experimented with.